# SQL server agent job to execute SSIS package without a proxy account

Tags: ssis

I created a SSIS package that extracts data from a table in server 1 and load data into a text file in a folder in server 2(not in the same domain). My windows account has access to this shared folder in the other domain. Then I created a SQL server agent job. In the job step properties tab, type was selected as SQL Server integration service package. Package source was selected as file system.
If I execute the package under SQL server agent service account, I get an error saying I need a proxy account. So I created a proxy account using my windows credentials. Now it runs fine. I tested this on development server. However, my manager does not want to implement this (proxy account method) on production server, as it uses my windows credentials.
Is there another way to do this? If so, can you please help me.
Thanks

Comment: You have the right idea, but just create a new account that is a system ID that you can use as the proxy account so your not using your own.